# What will break if I remove python2

Tags: debian, python

Suppose I do

```
cd /usr/bin
$ ll python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Jun  7 18:57 python -> python2
$ rm python
$ ln -s python3 python
$ rm pdb
$ ln -s pdb3 pdb
```

Can I know what will break? Perhaps `dpkg` or `apt`

Comment: Are you trying to make python3 your standard python?

Comment: @HarrysKavan yes. You can edit my heading and/or post body to reflect that better.

Comment: Do you really need it system wide and not just for a certain user?

Comment: To give you a short answer. You should not do that. Python2 is critical for a functioning Debian, chaging it to python3 will break a lot of stuff.

Comment: @HarrysKavan are you hinting that I put the new links in `~/bin` and put that in he head of `PATH` as less disasterous than a system-wide change?

Comment: @Harrys no, Python 2 isn’t critical for Debian (unlike Ubuntu). However doing this will break a lot of programs.

Comment: I'm hinting that you should learn how to use `virtualenv`, `update-alternatives --config python` or an `alias python=python3` in your `.bashrc`. Unlinking python2 from your system is probably the wrong way.

Comment: @HarrysKavan thank you so much for the pointers! Indeed I had not even heard of `virtualenv`, thinking that a small `virtualbox` image with python2 completely removed was my only alternative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`apt` can tell you:

```
apt -s remove python2.7
```

will list all the packages installed on your system which depend (directly or indirectly) on the Python 2 interpreter.

For finer-grained results, look at all the executables with a shebang pointing at `python`:

```
grep bin/python$ /usr/bin/*
```

All of those executables are liable to be broken by your change. You’ll no doubt see that this represents quite a few executables...

[PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) does allow what you’re doing (“for the time being, all distributions *should* ensure that `python`, if installed, refers to the same target as `python2`, **unless the user deliberately overrides this** or a virtual environment is active”, bold emphasis mine), but [Debian doesn’t support it](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/ch-python.html#s-base).

Comment: Peculiar output `...python3-smbc python3-tables...`.

Comment: @Vorac yes, some Python 3 packages end up depending on Python 2 (probably incorrectly).